# Form Multiple Combination Of String According To Square Bracket

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string (path) which have multiple square brackets and in every single square bracket, I can split them to multiple values. Now I am able to get the number of square brackets that exist in the string, split the value from the square brackets. I am facing issue whereby I don't really know how to form all possible combinations. Wish to have advice from members here. Thank you.

Example: `lib/abc/[max|min][_total]/_def[_adj|_adj2|_adj3].[lib|lab]`

Possible Combination:

```
lib/abc/max_total/_def_adj.lib
lib/abc/max_total/_def_adj2.lib
lib/abc/max_total/_def_adj3.lib
lib/abc/max_total/_def_adj.lab
lib/abc/max_total/_def_adj2.lab
lib/abc/max_total/_def_adj3.lab
```

and the same go to min as well.

I have try following code but it is only able to get the last value in the array. @number is the array to get the number of square brackets in the path. @number also add on backlash to support the regex substitution. @number_2 is the array to store of content in every square brackets. @number_3 is the array to store all value in square brackets.

```
    my @number = ($release_structure_split =~ /\[(.*?)\]/g);
    my $number_size = @number;
    my @number_2 = @number;
    my $number_2_size = @number_2;
    foreach my $number (@number){
        $number = '\['.$number.'\]';
        $number =~ s/\|/\\|/g;
    }
    for (my $m = 0; $m < $number_size; $m++){
        my $release_structure_split_temp = $release_structure_split;
        my @number_3 = split ('\|', $number_2[$m]);
        my $number_3_size = @number_3;
        if ($number_3_size == 1){
            push (@number_3, undef);
        }
        $number_3_size = @number_3;
        for (my $o = 0; $o < $number_3_size; $o++){
            if ($release_structure_split =~ $number[0] ){
                $release_structure_split =~ s/$number[0]/$number_3[0]/g;
                push (@release_structure_full_3, [$release_structure_full_2_unique[$l][0], $release_structure_split]);
            }
            elsif ($release_structure_split =~ $number_3[0]){
                $release_structure_split =~ s/$number_3[0]/$number_3[1]/g;
                push (@release_structure_full_3, [$release_structure_full_2_unique[$l][0], $release_structure_split]);
            }
            else{
                my $oo = $o - 1;
                $release_structure_split =~ s/$number_3[$oo]/$number_3[$o]/g;
                push (@release_structure_full_3, [$release_structure_full_2_unique[$l][0], $release_structure_split]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different approach uses [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).  First, format your string to make it compatible with `glob` by transliterating square brackets to curly braces, and pipes to commas.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'lib/abc/[max|min][_total]/_def[_adj|_adj2|_adj3].[lib|lab]';
$str =~ tr/[]|/{},/;
my @paths = glob $str;
```